# looping through columns to adjust formula

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

i have 3 rows of data and 17 columns, in row 2 depending on a selection (low, med, high, which is cell referenced as say 1, 2, 3) i want to have formula that if low is selected row 2 would equal corresponding column in row 1 and add 1.

effectively some code i was thinking of is:

```
For i = 2 to 17
Cells(2,i).Formula = "Cells(1,i) + 1"
```

I need the output to actually be a formula and not a value though

Comment: What would the formula be if you entered it manually in the worksheet?

Comment: for eg in my sheet it would be =B49+$B$43 for first column, C49+$B$43 and so forth and then for next row B50+$B$44 , C50 + $B$44

Comment: You can write a formula to a range in one go. You don't need a loop.

Comment: Maybe this way: `Cells(2, i).Formula = "=" & Cells(2, i).Offset(-1, 0).Address & "+1"`

Comment: Sam, I think you need to specify the address of the cell that holds the Low, Med, High (1, 2, 3) value, and also what formula you want in the Med and High cases. The answer is going to be close to @barneyos comment. Notice his `"="` and the `.Address`. Your question code contains Rows 1 and 2 but your example comment uses Rows 43, 44, 49, and 50. I'm having difficulty envisioning the exact goal.